# How to only user to edit/update/delete their own questions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user that has_many questions and questions belongs_to user. I'm trying to figure out how to only let the user `edit/delete/update` their own questions. I'm using devise for user authentication, but I can only figure out how to hide links such as 
`<% if user_signed_in? %>` show these links, but I only want to allow the current user to modify them (I assume there's some way to still access these links to edit/update/delete somehow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do what miahabdu wrote but then add validation to the methods in the controller. Just because a user can't see a link he could still just use the edit/update/delete URL. Just hiding links is only cosmetics. Something like:

```
    if question.user == current_user do
        .....do stuff
```

If not return some forbidden flash message explaining that they can only edit,update,delete their own message.

Hope it helps! Please don't just hide links as it does not help to secure user data.

Comment: I can add validations in the controller, but is just an id secure enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the question's user with current user and display the links based on that:

```
<% if @question.user == current_user %>
  # show edit/delete links
```

This way, only the user that posted the question would be able to view the links and edit/delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to both answers already posted, I recommend using a gem like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) where you can have elegant validations everywhere (you should validate at least on client and server sides).

Eg.

```
If user.can? :destroy @post
  do a barrel roll
end
#Disclaimer: Syntax correctness not ensued.
```

GL & HF.

Comment: Indeed, CanCan rocks!